# JIRA workflow diagram editor, does it work?

Tags: jira

I am new to JIRA. From a ClearQuest background, trying to get work done with JIRA. I have an evaluation v6.1 installed on Windows, can't get the workflow digram editor work both on Chrome and IE8 (it's a bank, we can't just upgrade my IE).

[IMG]http://i40.tinypic.com/f9fafc.jpg[/IMG]

BTW, can I get all work done in the text mode? I can live with that.

Thanks
Jirong

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Text mode even allows you some things the visual editor does not.

But since it's good to get an overview over complex workflows it's not bad to get it running. It works for me in IE8 after switching off compatibility mode (tools menu) for the site. If the window is too small to work properly try resizing the window, for me the flash frame with the editor then resizes as well.

Best way to go is Firefox, though, works fastest and most stable for me atm.

Comment: I used to use Firefox for everything, but today they have lots of pop-ups or other goofy stuffs. Completely dropped it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all the work in text mode. But Chrome should work just fine

Comment: My image shows how it looks in IE8(forgrand, nothing shows up), and Chrome (display in a very small area with scroll bars). I tried classic as well, nothing is working. I am using v6.1 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable Compat View in IE with all Atlassian products since it is not supported. If you are running the server in the intranet zone, it might automatically fall back to compat mode. There is a checkbox in IE settings where you can prevent this behaviour:
Tools -> Compatibility View Settings

as for Chrome, it should work. Maybe its a bug in the Jira release?

We are using 6.1.1 and the editor works fine in Chrome.

Comment: It works in IE8 after disable Compatibility, but doesn't looks good. Thanks.

Comment: It works in IE 10 and Chrome after I install the Adobe Frashplayer.